# How can I find rendered contents of Iframe page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have following page as coded:

mypage.html:

```
    <html><script>var a=document.createElement('p');
    a.innerHTML="hello world";
    document.body.appendChild(a);​​​​​​​​​​​</script>
    ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<body>
    <p>testing 1 2 3....</p></body>
   </html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

When I pull the information with find.html which has following code.

```
<script>
window.onload =finder();
function finder(){
var iframe=document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.width=1;
iframe.height=1;
iframe.src='mypage.html';
iframe.setAttribute('id', 'iframer');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    setTimeout(
        function() { 
var e = document.getElementById("iframer");
var frameHTML = e.contentDocument; var serializer = new XMLSerializer(); var content = serializer.serializeToString(frameHTML); alert(content);
        } , 30000);
}
</script>
```

the final result is showing as in alert popup:

```
    <html><script>var a=document.createElement('p');
    a.innerHTML="hello world";
    document.body.appendChild(a);​​​​​​​​​​​</script>
    ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<body>
    <p>testing 1 2 3....</p></body>
   </html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

That is not what I am looking for. I am looking to get contents as following which have been render in browser, i need to get all rendered and generated dynamic source code only for inspection, how can i code to get rendered HTML source code:

```
   <body>
   <p>hello world</p>
   <p>testing 1 2 3....</p>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the IFrame an `id` attribute.

The `contentDocument` object actually varies among different browsers. Also, for security reasons, you can only get the content of an IFrame on the same domain.

```
var IFrame_DOM;
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframer'); // The ID of the IFrame
if (iframe.contentDocument)
{
  IFrame_DOM = iframe.contentDocument; // Get DOM in Chrome / Gecko
}
else if (iframe.contentWindow)
{
  IFrame_DOM = iframe.contentWindow.document; // Internet Explorer
}
if (IFrame_DOM)
{
  // Successfully got the DOM
  // Use the DOM in code here
}
else
{
  alert('Unsupported Browser. Couldn\'t read DOM.');
}
```

Comment: I gave ID and attribute:
`iframe.setAttribute('id', 'iframer');`

Comment: And your first code  doesn't work at all in Chrome. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined ` And second code doesn't work either in Chrome too.`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined` Well, I need only rendered code, i don't really need actual source code with javascript function. All i need is all rendered code for inspection.

Comment: @user1541283 Edited answer. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use the xml serializer like this :

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var content = serializer.serializeToString('yourIframeObject;);
```

content variable contain the iframe contents including     `<!DOCTYPE html>` ,     `<HTML>` and          `<head>`